# how to transfer date from php into js

Tags: php, javascript

I've actual date from php script

```
$time_local_js = date('Y,m,d,H,i', strtotime('now'));
```

and I must to transfer it into js script

```
<span id="odliczanie"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
d_new=+new Date(2012,11,6,21,00,00);

d_old=new Date(); 

(function(){
sec=(d_new-d_old)/1000;
document.getElementById('odliczanie').innerHTML=~~(sec/(3600*24))+' days '+~~(sec/3600)%24+' hours '+~~(sec/60)%60+' min '+~~sec%60+' sek';
setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000)})()
</script>
```

into the variable 'd_old' (now it's temporarily `new Date()`). How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to echo the date into your javascript?

Comment: If you're just passing the 'now' date use a blank `Date()` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're outputting the file the includes the js with a php script.  If not, you'll need to.

The old line:

```
d_old=new Date();
```

The new line:

```
d_old=new Date(<?php echo $time_local_js ?>);
```

You're outputting the time of $time_local_js directly into the JS code that creates the value of d_old.

Answer (score 1):

```
d_old=new Date(<?=$time_local_js?>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to understand what PHP is and what Javascript is, understand that PHP is used to server-side generate the content to be rendered by browser. And javascript is a part of this content to be executed in the browser.

**Conclusion:** generate the adequate javascript in PHP.

This will lead you to the following solution: instead of

```
d_old=new Date();
```

in your javascript, write:

```
<?php echo "d_old=new Date(" . date('Y,m,d,H,i', strtotime('now')); . ");  ?>
```

Assuming you have it generated earlier, you can alternatively write:

```
d_old=new Date(<?echo $time_local_js; ?>);
```